# DOXYGEN, Eclox: Functions autocomplete not working with decorating macros

Tags: c++, macros, autocomplete, eclipse-plugin, doxygen

I have a problem with Eclox, the Doxygen plugin for Eclipse.

I use it to document my C/C++ code.

A reaaally nice feature of it is that it auto-generates comments for functions, when writing "/**" followed by an ENTER just before the function's definition.

Initial (code 1):

```
/** <--pressing enter after this results in code 2-->
int f(int a, int b)
```

Code after pressing enter (code 2):

```
/**
 *
 * @param a
 * @param b
 * @return
 */
int f(int a, int b)
```

The problem is that I use Microsoft's SAL syntax when writing my functions, and f would actually look like:

```
int f(__in int a, __in int b)
```

which confuses Eclox, and prevents it from auto-generating the @param & @return stuff. So I'm left with the following:

```
/**
 *
 */
int f(__in int a, __in int b)
```

even though __in is defined as empty in an included file:

```
#define __in
```

NOTE that if I paste the above define in THE SAME file, it works:

```
#define __in

/** <--now pressing enter here works as expected-->
int f(__in int a, __in int b)
```

Did anyone else encounter this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kind of solved my problem.

Not a perfect solution, neither a very good one but it does the job so the result is satisfying nonetheless.

In Eclipse: **right-click your C/C++ project->Properties->C/C++ General->Paths and Symbols->Symbols->Click the C language (GNU C in my case)**.

You can add **symbols** which will be taken-into-account by Eclox there: e.g. adding the symbol **__in** with an **empty** value solves the situation exemplified in my original question.

In my case, I would have to add **A LOT OF SYMBOLS** (as I said I decorate my functions using Microsoft's SAL), which would take a lot of time if done directly from Eclipse. Instead I add just one symbol and click **Export Settings** which exports them to an **XML** for which you can make a **script** to add your entries to and which you can import afterwards by using **Import Settings**.

Or similarly you can edit your **.cproject** file directly (I suggest you first backup it), if you wish to add those settings to **ALL project configurations** at once, just search for you added symbol and you'll find that it's defined there.

Next to **Paths and Symbols** there is also **Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros etc.**. You can use that as well, it is setup similarly, with the note that you'd have to add the macros to **CDT User Setting Entries**. I've tried adding an **Include File** entry or a **Preprocessor Macros File** entry instead of adding **Preprocessor Macro** entries, but it didn't work.